# Using ZModem inside command-line on Windows for file transfer over Serial

Tags: linux, windows, file-transfer, serial-port

I need to transfer large files from Windows to an embedded Linux system over Serial port. People seems to be recommending **ZModem** to do this task. Using TeraTerm's file transfer feature, I was able to carry out this task successfully.

My question is, how can I use this outside of TeraTerm, and in a commandline environment on Windows? I've downloaded precompiled binaries (rz.exe and sz.exe), but fell short when it does not let you specify the COM port to perform the file transfer to. I'm looking to do something like this

`./sz.exe filename.zip > COM10`

From the manual page, it doesn't look like it provide any option to specify the serial port. Am I missing something? Any insights are greatly appreciated.

Jonathan

Comment: I have exactly this question, did you ever figure it out?

Comment: Unfortunately I was not able to figure it out after a couple weeks of researching. I ended up resorting to using USB composite (serial + storage) on my linux USB driver, and transfer file to the USB storage while maintaining communication with serial.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how strict 'outside of Tera Term' is, you could try using a TeraTerm [macro](https://ttssh2.osdn.jp/manual/4/en/macro/), which reads like a programming script and can be executed from the command line. Macros have pretty reasonable capabilities; I've just made one which connects to a raspberry pi over TCP (but would work with serial), logs in, prompts the user to select a file then sends said file over ZMODEM.

Comment: @Issac can you share how to do it in a Windows PC?

Comment: @Daniel pretty much all the documentation you need should be in that link, and is correct for Windows. It's been almost a year since I last used my program and I don't have the code anymore, but you'll need the `zmodemsend` command. One thing I do remember is that for any file larger than (I think) a few kB, zmodem over serial isn't 100% reliable and is quite slow